# JavaScript or JQuery to make an element behave like a link - onmouseover or hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onmouseover, jquery-hover

Well, this time I have a rather sticky problem: make a TR row of a HTML table behave like a hyperlink. :/ Unfortunately I can't change the basic structure of HTML to use DIVs (due to coding requirements - it's a long story).

## So what's the problem?

Basically, I know that the **onclick** (JavaScript) or **click** (JQuery) will link these elements up to the pages I need, and I have implemented these solutions with success. However, **I would like them to act like hyperlinks *while the user is hovering***, so that the user sees (via the "hand" or whatever hover icon in his browser) that he is looking at a link, and can right-click and open in a new window.

I know that I can use **onmouseover** and **hover** methods for respectively JavaScript and JQuery. The problem is, I haven't the faintest idea what code to put in such methods to make them work the way I need, and my search on Google has been thus far fairly fruitless. :/

## My working code thus far

### With HTML and JavaScript

My HTML:

```
<tr class = "oneResultat" onclick="DoNav('annonce.php')">
    ...
</tr>
```

And JavaScript:

```
function DoNav(url)
{
    document.location.href = url;
}
```

### With HTML and JQuery

My HTML:

```
<tr class = "oneResultat" href = "annonce.php">
    ...
</tr>
```

My JQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".oneResultat").click(function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).attr("href");
    });
});
```

Comment: why do not you use css for this? `tr.oneResultat { cursor: pointer; }`  if you can not edit the stylesheet, you can use js or jQuery to manipulate this property of element.

Comment: i understand he wants the browser to show the link address on hover, which is not possible with css(unless u make a tooltip, but he wants it to be native)

Comment: I'm sure he understands the `cursor: pointer;` but the difficult part is the right click - > open in new tab function. I'd be interested in seeing someone figure out how to do this. That's why I voted up.

Comment: @SergeySob and SpencerMay are right. The closer I can get to actual hyperlink behavior, the ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get default anchor handling in the browser - is to use anchors! But since you can't wrap the `TR` in an anchor, you must wrap the contents of each `TD` in an anchor. This will work best if your `TD`'s are rendered without gaps between them.

HTML:

```
<tr class="oneResultat" data-href="annonce.php"> ... </tr>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $oneTR = $(".oneResultat");
  var href = $oneTR.attr("href");
  var wrap = "<a href='"+href+"'></a>";
  $("tr.oneResultat > td").wrapInner(wrap);
});
```

Possible CSS to make the anchors display full-width in the TD's:

```
tr.oneResultat > td > a {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Note this creates regular anchors which are triggered by left-click, not right-click. If you must use right-click, then make the anchors `href='#'` and attach an event handler for `click` on those anchors, then invoke one of the many jQuery contextmenu plugins to render a context-sensitive menu. Let me know if you want an example of that, but for now I'll assume you want regular left-click browser anchor behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

you can embed the `td` content inside an `<a>` tag, or you can plant a 'transparent' `<a>` tag with no content(but address), that will be absolutely positioned and cover the whole `<tr>`.
See here:
http://jsbin.com/gelezubake/1/edit?html,output

the right click -> open is possible with JS catching the right mouse button click and tooltip over, with an option to open new window(window.open with arguments)

Comment: you should NOT put a block content in `a` tag it works but it's bad

Comment: I prefer this solution as well, else it will need a lot of work to make not anchor behave like real anchor, specially with right click  menu

Comment: i didnt say to put a TD inside <a>, but TD's content inside <a>!
ps. td is not block, its table-cell, BTW

Comment: my apologies, my dev body have a deficit of `coffee`

Answer (score 1):

you can use css `cursor: pointer;`

> The cursor property specifies the type of cursor to be displayed when pointing on an element.

```
.oneResultat {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

---

edit:

for right click context menu I wrote js that listen to context menu on tr and append a on the event target (td) once relese the context the a remove and the html reappend to the td.

```
(function(){
var item, isIntextMenuOpen;

$('[data-href]')
.on('click', function(e){
        window.document.location = $(this).attr('data-href');
})
.on('contextmenu', function(e){
    var href=$(this).attr('data-href');

    item=$(e.target);
    item.wrapInner('<a href="'+href+'">');
    isIntextMenuOpen = true;
});

function hideContextmenu(e){
       if(isIntextMenuOpen ){
          var children = item.children('a'),
          $child = $(children[0]),
          html = $child.html();

           $child.remove();
           item.html(html);

       }

     isIntextMenuOpen = false;
}
$(window).blur(hideContextmenu);

$(document).click(hideContextmenu);
})();
```

working jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/qovejasuso/1/

Answer (score 0):

your class oneResultat should be in a css file or style attribute like:

```
<style>
tr.oneResultat {
   text-decoration: underline;
   cursor: pointer;
}

tr.oneResultat:hover {
   color: #0000ee;
}

tr.oneResultat:visited {
   color: #747EBD;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using table tags, use divs with these css properties

replace **`<table>`** with **`<div class="table">`**
replace **`<tr>`** with **`<div class="tr">`**
replace **`<td>`** with **`<div class="td">`**

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
}

.td {
  display: table-cell;
}
```